# How to extract destination MAC from PCAP?

Tags: mac-address, wireshark, pcap

I have PCAPs collected at the Raspberry Pi (from this [paper](http://www.uel.br/grupo-pesquisa/secmq/dataset-iot-security.html)). I want to extract the following headers:

- Ether header (3)
- IP header (12)
- TCP header (10)
- UDP header (4)

Then convert the PCAP into csv. 
But I could not extract Ether header (specifically: ether.dst). So, How can I extract all required headers' data?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't see the ethernet header because you are not capturing traffic on an Ethernet interface.

You are using the Linux cooked-mode capture. As per [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51363622/6829739), which itself refers to [The Wireshark Wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SLL) this mode doesn't provide the link-layer header.

From the above Wiki page:

> When capturing from the "any" device, or from one of those other
>   devices, in Linux, the libpcap doesn't supply the link-layer header
>   for the real "hardware protocol" like Ethernet, but instead supplies a
>   fake link-layer header for this pseudo-protocol.

So to get the data you want you need to capture traffic on the ethernet interface itself.